# What data is collected by "Turn on logging in Communicator"?

Tags: logging, ms-office-communicator

In Communicator, there are a few logging options available in the Options dialog.

- Under Personal:

  - Save my instant message conversations in the Outlook Conversation History folder.
  - Save my call logs in the Outlook Conversation History folder.
- Under General:

  - Turn on logging in Communicator
  - Turn on Windows Event logging for Communicator

The first two options are fairly straightforward - they do what they say they do.

The last two are a bit more ambiguous.  Here's my questions:

- What "logging" does "Turn on logging in Communicator" enable exactly, and where is it stored?
- I presume "Turn on Windows Event logging" sends some logs to the Event Viewer (eventvwr.exe) but what gets logged there?
- How do these options differ from each other, in data collection and storage terms?

The General tab has a "More Information..." button in the Logging section, but that only takes you to a Privacy Statement - this tells you what Microsoft will and won't do with the information that is collected, but doesn't tell you what information *is* collected by which specific feature.

Comment: BTW:  I'm totally okay with moving this to SF if that's more appropriate.

Comment: Why would this be better on Server Fault? I don't know much about Communicator, but it _seems_ on-topic for SU. Is it server software? If you think it's better there, you could delete your question here and re-ask on SF.

Comment: @nhinkle - Communicator is enterprise-level software - not your standard MSN Messenger.  So, I figured the ServerFault community might have a bit more knowledge.  Generally, when a question is mis-placed, I'd rather migrate than delete and re-create.

Comment: I think it's on-topic for SU, but if you really want it migrated to SF, let me know and we can do that. It does look like there are a bunch of questions about Communicator on SF, so it'll probably be an OK fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The page that opens when you click on the "Help" button in this dialog](http://office.microsoft.com/client/helppreview.aspx?AssetID=HA010290016&ns=COMM2007R2&lcid=1033&pc=oc&ver=3&subver=5&bld=6907&bldver=225#BM6) has some of the information you're looking for.

> **Turn on logging in Communicator** You can enable this option to create a log file, Communicator-uccapi-0.uccapilog, that contains information about the interaction of Office Communicator 2007 R2 with Office Communications Server 2007 R2. The Communicator-uccapi-0.uccapilog file is created in the Windows \Tracing folder. This option also creates a Communicator.etl file, which is trace file that is created for administrators and Microsoft Customer Service and Support to help troubleshoot issues.
>
> **NOTE**   To enable **Turn on logging in Communicator**, you must be a member of the Performance Log Users group.
>
> **Turn on Windows Event logging for Communicator** Select this option to turn on Windows Event logging for Communicator. Events can be viewed in the Windows Event Viewer.

There is also an article on Microsoft TechNet that goes into more details about [Windows event logging in Communicator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd572520%28office.13%29.aspx):

> When logging is enabled on a client, Communicator writes the following types of errors to the Windows system event log, along with detailed troubleshooting information:
>
> - Errors that prevent a user from signing in to the server, such as host or domain name errors, or an invalid certificate.
> - Diagnostic messages returned by the server, such as version check failures, problems with sign-in credentials, or errors generated in response to a SIP INVITE message from the client.
> - Windows event trace log (ETL) files, which may also be generated on your computer in the /Tracing folder, enable administrators and Microsoft support technicians troubleshoot problems. For details, contact your Microsoft Customer Service and Support representative.